# Qt: How to Access Inherited Widget?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, widget, qpushbutton

I'm creating a custom widget that extends the `QPushButton` class. My question is how to reference the button that is automatically placed in the widget when extending `QPushButton`? Getting `parentWidget()` returns the `QMainWindow` above it, obviously, so I'm not sure what that widget is called for me to reference, either with the `this` keyword or otherwise.

For example, if my custom class does nothing but inherit the `QPushButton` class:

```
CustomButton::CustomButton(QWidget *parent) 
    : QPushButton(parent) 
{
}
```

And my `MainWindow` class just instantiates a instance of that custom button:

```
HomeWindow::HomeWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    CustomButton btn = new CustomButton(this);
}
```

Qt automatically adds a `QPushButton` from the inheritance:
[screenshot of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXwVH.png)

My question is how to access that `QPushButton` that is automatically added when inheriting from `QPushButton` so I can handle its click event and resize it from within the `CustomButton` class. I just am looking to call something like `this->inheritedWidget()`in `CustomButton.cpp` but don't know what that would be.

Thank you!

ANSWER:
I was looking to handle resizes with an overload of `setMinimumSize()` but couldn't figure out how to access the inherited `QPushButton` widget. You can access the inherited button's functions just with `QPushButton::setMinimumSize()`or whatever other function you'd need to call. Probably a simple question but glad to have figured it out. thanks, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could do with a example to make it more clear.

But, if what you are doing is something like

```
class MyWidget : public QPushButton {
```

Then you can access (`public` and `protected`) members of your base class just like you access members of the part of the class you write yourself. Nothing special is required, just mention the base class member by name, just like you would a member you added in the derived class.

A trivial example:

```
class Base {
protected:
    int base_int;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int derived_int;
public:
    int getBaseInt() const { return base_int; }
    int getDerivedInt() const { return derived_int; }
};
```

If there's an ambiguity (say both base and derived have members of the same name), then you can resolve that ambiguity by refering to Base members by their fully qualified name:

```
int getBaseInt() const { return Base::base_int; }
```

But you very rarely need to do that.